# Не могу получить все ответы от сервера

Tags: java, android

Не удается получить в приложение все ответы от сервера. 
Ответ идет вида:

```
{"id":"14","story":[{"name":"Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT ","author":"1"}]}
{"id":"13","story":[{"name":"Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол ","author":"1"}]}
{"id":"12","story":[{"name":"Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу ","author":"1"}]}
{"id":"10","story":[{"name":"Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык ","author":"1"}]}
{"id":"9","story":[{"name":"Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус ","author":"1"}]}
```

Я хочу получить ответы от сервера, но у меня удается получить лишь первую строку, то есть только

```
{"id":"14","story":[{"name":"Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT ","author":"1"}]}
```

И на этом все. Перерыл все сайты, не нашел решение.
Делаю так:

```
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String TAG_STORY = "story";

protected String doInBackground(String[] args) {

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_story, "GET", params);

        try {

            JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STORY);
                       for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++)
                       {
                          System.out.println("Статья:" + results.get(i));
                       }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В том ответе сервера, который вы приводите - 4 ответа. Видимо берется один из них. Чтобы ответ был один отправляйте клиенту такой JSON:

```
{response: [
  {"id":"14","story":[{"name":"Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT ","author":"1"}]},
  {"id":"13","story":[{"name":"Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол ","author":"1"}]},
  {"id":"12","story":[{"name":"Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу ","author":"1"}]},
  {"id":"10","story":[{"name":"Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык Мурлык ","author":"1"}]},
  {"id":"9","story":[{"name":"Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус Страус ","author":"1"}]}
]}
```

Я никогда не писал на Java, но разбор будет примерно следующий:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String TAG_RESPONSE = "response";
private static final String TAG_STORY = "story";

protected String doInBackground(String[] args) {

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_story, "GET", params);

    try {
        JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE); // Массив из историй
                   for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++)   // Перебор массива историй (4 элемента)
                   {
                      JSONArray history = results.get(i).getJSONArray(TAG_STORY);
                      for(int j = 0; j < history.length(); j++)   // Перебор истории
                      {

                         System.out.println("Статья:" + history.get(j));
                      }
                   }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: А если в дальнейшем мне нужно будет разобрать каждый ответ и вставить его в ListView , это не помешает мне этого сделать? И с моим вариантом ответа от сервера нельзя разве никак получить все 4 ответа?

Comment: @Денис дополнил. Разбор будет примерно такой. Я не знаю что такое ListView.

Comment: На строку `JSONArray history = results.get(i).getJSONArray(TAG_STORY);` ругается Eclipse **The method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type Object**

Comment: @Денис значит `results.get(i)` - объект, и у него есть свойство-массив `store`. Я ещё немного код поправил, во вложенном цикле итератор поменял.